# How to test Flutter app with Firebase and BLoC?

Tags: firebase, testing, flutter, bloc

Is there any efficient solution to test a BLoC which calls Firebase Functions?
You can mock the Firebase calls, but then you have to bring this mock into your BLoC. So how do I handle this the best way possible?